# MySQL Error in query statements

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to acquaint myself on Mysql syntax.  I only have used MSSQL so far.  I downloaded the MySQL Query Browser and have installed the MySQL Version 5.1

I wanted to run this line of code in the resultset tab of MySQL but I keep on encountering below error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare iCtr int' at line 1

Code:

```
declare iCtr int;
set iCtr = 1;

while iCtr < 1000
begin
    insert into employee (emp_id,emp_first_name,emp_last_name,status_id)
      values (iCtr, 'firstName' + iCtr, 'lastName' + iCtr, 1)
      set iCtr = iCtr + 1;
end
```

I just wanted to populate my employees table but I cannot get past the MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

I think that might be the trouble?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried what you have suggested but I still encounters the same error. Any other hints please.

Comment: what did you try, and what is the new error? Because the linenumber must have changed at least ;)

Comment: I tried what you have suggested the error is like this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare iCtr int' at line 2 =)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
DELIMITER $$


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `procedurename`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `procedurename`()
BEGIN
        declare iCtr int;
set iCtr = 1;

while iCtr < 1000 do

    insert into employee (emp_id,emp_first_name,emp_last_name,status_id)
      values (iCtr, 'firstName' + iCtr, 'lastName' + iCtr, 1);
      set iCtr = iCtr + 1;
end while;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can I execute SQL statements on the fly without making them a procedure in Mysql?  Thanks

Comment: @Mark: As per my knowledge, you can do it in two ways, first, making dynamic query using language like PHP and then you can execute it using mysql functions which are available with PHP. Second, If you want to do with mysql itself, then you will need to use procedure as i suggested . Hope this helps.